# Using generic interface in the repository pattern

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am currently developing an MVC 3 application with EF and the Repository pattern. I created a generic interface as follows:

```
interface IGenericRepository<T>
{
}
```

And an abstract class as follows:

```
abstract class GenericRepository<TContext ,T> : IGenericRepository<T>
    where TContext : DbContext, new()
{
}
```

After that my repo inherits both of them like this:

```
interface ICardRepository : IGenericRepository<Card>
{
}
```

and

```
class CardRepository : GenericRepository<EfContext, Card>, 
    ICardRepository
{
}
```

With Unity I register the interface and the class like this:

```
container.RegisterType<ICardRepository, CardRepository>();
```

Now the question is: can I use IGenericRepository instead of `ICardRepository`?
Like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IGenericRepository<Card>, CardRepository>();
```

In theory I can, but as I still do not get how this pattern works I am not quite sure if I am not breaking or missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible issue is now you will have to resolve `IGenericRepository<Card>`, instead of `ICardRepository`.

This will not work:

```
var cardRepository = container.Resolve<ICardRepository>();
```

Instead you will have to do this:

```
var cardRepository = container.Resolve<IGenericRepository<Card>>();
```

This also means that if you are doing something like constructor injection, you can't use:

```
public class SomethingDependentOnCardRepository
{
    // The parameter type should be IGenericRepository<Card> instead,
    // if you are using Unity to resolve this dependency.
    public SomethingDependentOnCardRepository(ICardRepository cardRepository)
    {
       // code
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually I am aware of that. The point is if I use the interface like that am I breaking the pattern in some way? For example (I know that this is not the case) I might make testing harder if I use the generic interface.

Comment: Ah. I can't think of any potential problems with this.  My only concern is what purpose would the ICardRepository interface serve at this point?  Or would that be removed in the process?

Comment: I want to get rid of that interface and instead use only the generic interface - it will save me from creating numerous copies of the same interface with different name like ICardRepository, ITagRepository, ISomethingElseRepository, which are basically the same.

Comment: If your repositories don't do anything why do you have them in the first place? [This is the latest](http://ayende.com/blog/153701/ask-ayende-life-without-repositories-are-they-worth-living) of a series of posts by Oren Eini (aka. Ayende Rahien) where he argues against the repository pattern. Google will give you more of his arguments.

Comment: It does not matter what they do or they don't :) - I needed to know if I am breaking the pattern in some way. Actually IGenericRepository has the following methods: GetSingle, GetAll, Add, Remove. I know that repositories are disputable, but I have to stick to EF and besides that I have to develop the project in a tight timeframe. Later I can alter it in a better way, but for now I will stick to what I already (almost) know.

Comment: I use a generic `IRepository<T>` where the `T : EntityBase`. This allows me to define common properties once (eg `Id`, `RecordStatus`), access those properties from within the generic repository and modify lambdas on-the-fly (I effectively add an `AND RecordStatus = Active` to all lambdas if the repository doesn't have the `IncludeDeleted` property set). Personally, I find it very powerful & flexible.